# contextmenu is not opening on right clicking div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using contextmenu.js (jQuery context menu plugin) for opening the context menu on right clicking of div. But somehow only default menu is opening. I am not able to locate the exact problem.

On debugging, it is showing that on its right click it is attaching the context menu to div. But when I right click div, default menu opens.

I know I am providing very limited information but any suggestion and help will be appreciable.

Comment: Can you provide some more infomration? What is your code to setup the plugin, etc.? You tried to call a `preventDefault()` on the click event? Is the plugin cross-browser compatible? May this will help you: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/#demo

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have used the same plugin.

Comment: Thanks.Though I have not called preventDefault(), but I have used the same plugin. Should I use the preventDefault?If yes can you please guide me for that?

Comment: I looked at the documentation, I think `preventDefault` will not help, I postet an answer that you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this, if that is your element that should get the menu

```
<div id="item-1">This should have a menu</div>
```

Then your javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#item-1').contextMenu({
    menue: 'menueName'
  },
  function(action, el, pos) {
    // do sth when the menu was clicked
    alert('Action ' + action + ' was clicked on ' + $(el).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

The menue itselfe should defined in a list like:

```
<ul id="#menueName" class="contextMenu">
  <li class="action1">
    <a href="#action1>Action 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="action1">
    <a href="#action2>Action 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also make sure you have jQuery 1.3 or above included in your page.

Comment: Doing in the same way. But using $(function() in place of $(document).ready(function(). Actually it is working fine in a dummy application but when I embed it in my project it does not work.In my project we have also other libraries like prototype, jsAddins etc. Can this be a problem?

Comment: ok can you try to remove the `$(function() { ... });`, may this work for you? Because this means the code is not called on pageload in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Replacing `if(jQuery)( function() {` at the beginning of jquery.contextMenu.js with `(function($, undefined){` fixed the problem. I hope that helps.